# Why should concurrent.futures' "finishing methods" only be used by Executor implementations and unit tests"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, future, concurrent.futures

The documentation of [`concurrent.futures.Future.set_result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.set_result) says

> This method should only be used by `Executor` implementations and unit tests.

The same says the documentation of `set_exception()` and  set_running_or_notify_cancel()`.

But I can imagine using (and in Java also have used in the past) `Future` objects for (slightly) other purposes resp. in slightly different circumstances. In these cases, I'd just like to use a Future object. Why is this discouraged?

In order to become a little clearer: I talk about a quite complex sequence of events which involve two different schedulers and stuff, and a `Future` object could be used to cancel this process as well as notify about its completion. This framework is not an `Executor` (nor can it be one).

Answer (score 1):

What the documentation says is that the `set_result()` method, not the `Future` object itself, should only be used by an implementation.

The rationale seems obvious to me: The result of a future should be the outcome of the work encapsulated by the Future object, but the work itself (the code that you want to run asynchronously) should not care how it is being executed. So who should be allowed to define what the `result()` method returns? Only the framework that schedules and launches the tasks.

In your example, you can pass Future objects around, cancel them or check their status or retrieve the result (with `result()`). None of these operations require you to use `set_result()`. But as you explained in the comments, your framework is not based on the `Executor` class (by inheritance or by implementing the Executor interface) but still it is an *Executor work-alike.* Therefore, I would say using the `set_result()` method is in conformance with the spirit of the comment that are concerned about.

Incidentally, have you considered tweaking your framework so that it *does* offer a compatible implementation of the Executor interface? It would be conceptually nice and might make some things easier to maintain and work with in the future.

Comment: In my intended use case, it is my framework (which is not an `Executor`) which creates `Future()` objects, checks its `canceled()` status and sets its result.

Comment: If it does all that, it sounds like an alternative Executor implementation to me :-) If you manage the scheduling, execute the work and record the result, you are writing an executor imho.

Comment: Yes and no. I don't have anything which derives from `Executor`, and my frmwork doesn't have a `.submit()`. But apart from that, you are right. So I just leave it the way I did it. Thank you!

Comment: Makes sense. So you have a partial or work-alike implementation of the Executor interface, not a fully compatible one. In any event deriving from `Executor` is not a requirement, since Python follows "duck typing" :-)